# Cascading Delete Entity Framework 4 .How do you do it?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a customer with many Addresses .Deleting the customer should delete all the customerAddresses too.
Provided I have sql server table "Customer" set up to have cascade delete

Is there anything special I need to do to make it work?

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It will just works. Cascading delete in a database is picked up by EDM Wizard and you will be having the same rule on your model's associations and it is recommended to have cascade in both the model and the database, or in neither to avoid incorrect expectations and unpredictable results.

Comment: If In the model browser I have "Updated from database" i assume it will pick it up and there will be nothing for me todo no? Or is something I have todo manually in the model?

Comment: No problem and yes it works. Although you don't need to do anything in this regard, you can still double check your association's OnDelete action to make sure that they got picked up by EF from your database.